# Deploying nextjs to vercel

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build, next.js, vercel

**I'm trying to deploy a next app to vercel, but getting this error at build**

[image]

I'm *not getting any error* on my local when I build, but It causes an error on vercel build
please resolve my issue.

Comment: Did you commit node_modules folder too accidentally ?

Comment: @SiddharthVarangaonkar No I did not commit node_modules folder.

Comment: What is ArchiveBlogs? Do you have a page with name aor whatever? You have an error rendering pages. Do you use environment variables?

Answer (score 2):

If you have no errors on `local build` but you have an error on `vercel build` it means `you are missing some info on vercel`.

In 95% cases it's `environment variables` `(Vercel->settings->environment variables)`.

Also, you can't use "hardcoded code" like `http://localhost` etc. So any time you can have variable changing as `localhost`, you need to define in in your `local env` and `vercel env`.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late but do you have ESLint in your dependencies or devDependencies in the package.json?

It's just a hypothesis but if you had ESLint installed globally on your machine and did not have it in the package.json, the project would work in your machine but fail in vercel (since you never told vercel you need ESLint).

If I'm right, adding ESLint to your package.json (`yarn add --dev eslint`) should solve it.
Note that the error tells you to run the same command, so I'm quite confident...